# Sql server table to Sharepoint list

Tags: sql, sharepoint

Anyone knows of a easy way to export a sql server table to a sharepoint list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint 2010:

[How to: Create an External Content Type Based on a SQL Server Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557243.aspx)

Comment: Thx, actually a better idea than mine as i was aiming to import the data instead of connecting

Answer (score 0):

If you will use SSIS to perform the export, take a look at the [SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652) in the [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.